# Converting href view Html code to php

Tags: php, html

Hi guygs im having a hard time transforming this html code to php

```
 <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $user; ?>/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
```

I tried this but it didnt work....

```
 echo "<td><input type = 'submit' value = 'DEL' name='submit' style = 'font-size:12px'></td>\n";
```

Edit:

```
 <a href="uploads/$USER;/$row['file']" target="_blank">view file</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean `didn't work`?

Comment: what you need to convert please give full code and exaltation

Comment: error code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'uploads' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Finalv10\upload.php on line 128

Comment: @S.I. Semicolon is optional in that case

Comment: @ShiraNai7 correct. Try this way `<a href="uploads/"<?php echo $user; ?>"/"<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a>`

Comment: @DingoDile, clarify which html code you want to transform in php? at the first line you have wrote is not clear as it having already php code. just paste pure HTML code and add your VARIABLE in caps letter so that can help for answer